# Windows command line - Remove files with specific extension, but not ones where extension contains substring (doc not docx)

Tags: windows, cmd, del

I'm using wordconv.exe to convert a bunch of a old doc files into docx.   Afterwards I'd like to delete the original doc files.

When I run "del /S *.doc" on the command line it deletes both the doc and docx files.  Anyway to get it to delete just .doc files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to use something like this:

```
forfiles /s /m *.doc /c "cmd /c del @file"
```

Comment: You need to use `@relpath` or `@path` instead of `@file`, because `forfiles` uses the path after the `/P` option, which defaults to `.`, as the working directory for the command behind `/C`, so any items in sub-directories will not be found; in addition, regard that `forfiles` iterates both files and folders, but there is a meta-variable `@isdir` to check...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the short 8.3 names of the files, because for internal `cmd` commands and also many external ones, wild-cards (`*`, `?`) also match against them. For example, a file like `important-document.docx` has got a short name like `import~1.doc`, which is matched by `*.doc`.

There are some commands that treat wild-cards differently:

- [`forfiles`](http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html) (as already demonstrated in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51754085) by [Michał Mielczarek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8365453)):

  ```cmd
  forfiles /S /M "*.doc" /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE del @relpath"
  ```

  The `@isdir` query checks whether the current item is a file and lets skip folders.
- [`where`](http://ss64.com/nt/where.html):

  ```cmd
  for /F "delims=" %%F in ('set "PATHEXT=" ^& where /R "." "*.doc"') do @del "%%~F"
  ```

  The surrounding [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) captures the result of `where`. The command `set "PATHEXT="` deletes the `PATHEXT` variable in the `cmd` instance in which `where` is executed, because this also regards that variable, so a file like `important-document.doc.com` could also be matched unintentionally with a default value of `PATHEXT` of `.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD`, for instance.

  Although the `where` approach appears a little bit more complicated, you might prefer it, because it is faster than `forfiles`, particularly when having a huge directory tree.

N. B.:

`forfiles /M "*.*"` does not match files (or folders) with no extension (so use `/M "*"` to match something like `testfile`), but `where "*.*"` does, so this indicates that these two commands have their own individual wild-card handling/substitution routines.

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%? in ('dir /b /a-d /s *.doc') do if  /i "%%~x?"==".doc"  del "%%~f?"
```

You can add `if exist "%%~dpn?.docx"` before del, if .doc and .docx are in same folder.